# Port 30005 and 30006 in ADSL router

Tags: port, adsl-router

I've seen that iptables allow traffic to ports 30005(tcp) and 30006(udp). What is those port intended for?

I've google a bit but I didn't find anything significative.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Port `30005` is used by the trojan "Backdoor JZ" and "Litmus".

See [here](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=30005) and [here](http://www.auditmypc.com/tcp-port-30005.asp).

I'm not saying you're infected but if you don't know who opened these ports it worth checking your computer.

Can you check if there are processes using these ports?

Answer (score 1):

Some DSL routers use port 30005-30007 for remote management (TR69 Management) purpose

Comment: A valid answer, confirmed for Sky Telecom.